# How to set virtual directory for php

Tags: php, eclipse, apache

I am learning php. I am learning through by looking at structure of existing web site. I can configure it correctly.

I dont how to set the virtuall directory for web site. Like ASP.NET you have either host the site on IIS or you can use local ISS. Is there any such thing with PHP.

I am using eclipse for development.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only running a single site on your Apache server, then you simply have to set the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#documentroot) and [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory) entries to match your document root.

Comment: how can i set documentRoot and directory ??

Comment: @huzaifa: *Read* the documentation in the links. You have to edit your httpd.conf file.